# Java GUI Swing Model Explanation

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I've been working with Swing for a while now but the whole model/structure of `JFrame`s, `paint()`, `super`, etc is all murky in my mind.
I need a clear explanation or link that will explain how the whole GUI system is organized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same happened to me. Actually to this day I don't quite get 100% how all it works.

Swing is a very flexible framework - perhaps too flexible. With flexibility comes a lot of abstraction and with abstraction comes confusion. :)

I've found the following articles worth reading. They helped me to better understand the big picture of Swing.

- [A Swing Architecture Overview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html)
- [The process of installing a UI delegate](https://web.archive.org/web/20110815102419/http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/ui_install/index.html), which is just this image:

  [image: The process of installing a UI delegate]

They explain quite well how the model and the delegate work. It always drives me mad when I see those `JLabel`, `LabelUI`, `ui.update`, etc.

Comment: Very useful link - had not seen that before; bookmarked for a closer look later.

Comment: Yeahh ... I don't remember how I came to that link. I didn't found it until after several years.   I don't know  the "google search" to produce it either, so I have it in my bookmarks too.

Comment: @OscarRyz links are dead. do you have the copy? i need those for my students. thanks.

Comment: @ihsan Unfortunately the site in Oracle has broken images:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html Fortunately we have the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20110413222135/http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Java Swing Tutorial (click [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/))? It does a pretty good job of covering the basics of developing Swing applications.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged with `JFrame`, I'll suggest a few links for understanding how `JFrame`s and other top-level Swing containers work.

I also found that Swing was (and still is) quite involved and taking a look at the documentation provided by Sun is required every once in a while -- Every time I check, I seem to learn something new.

First, the basics: [`JFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) class from the Java API Specifications. The Java API Specifications often provide good detailed information about the classes. In this instance, you'll notice that there are several links such as [How to Make Frames](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) section from The Java Tutorials.

Aside from that, I'll also recommend looking at the [Lesson: Using Swing Components](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) from The Java Tutorials. The lesson provides instructions on how to use the components provided in Swing along with some useful examples.

For more specifics parts that I've found confusing when I started with Swing was all the different types of panes, such as the `ContentPane`, `RootPane`, `GlassPane`. The [Using Top-Level Containers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) section provides information and helpful diagrams on the container hierarchy of the top-level containers.  The [How to Use Root Panes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) section gets into the details about the Glass, Layered, and Content Panes with plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Swing Explorer](https://swingexplorer.dev.java.net/) to be a precious tool to understand the hierarchy of components (particularly in complex GUIs) and look at properties (alas, read-only: we get used to Firebug convenience!). It has an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/) by Chet Haase and Romain Guy is a great book about Java UI. It covers some more advanced stuff too, but introduction and few first chapters explain fundamental things well.

Answer (score 0):

If, after reading the Swing tutorial, you find your interest lies in more advanced topics, you may also wish to look at [Swing Second Edition](http://manning.com/robinson2/) by Robinson and Vorobiev.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that simply browsing around in the source code (ctrl-click on a name if you're using NetBeans) has been really helpful. If I see a method appear in the completion dialog that I'm not familiar with, I'll just click "Go to source" and look around until I'm comfortable with it.